# How to Encrypt Active Directory Attributes?

Tags: encryption, active-directory

I have some custom attributes in Active Directory. The attributes are populated via code.

Does AD support automatic encryption/decryption of the values stored in these attributes or should my code do the encryption/decryption prior to  writing/reading the attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What syntax (Case Insensitive String, Unicode String, etc) did you make the attributes when you added them?

Really, that doesn't matter as you'll just be setting the values when writing to AD so you'll have to do the Encryption/Decryption yourself.